# cycles hair strand uv coordinate

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, node-editor, hair

I would like to create uv coordinate locally for each hair particule ribbons strand

I have created a plane with ribbon hair particules:
[image]

I would like my texture to be aligned for each strand.

Here are the piece of information I have found on nodes:

HairInfo.Intercept contains 0 to 1 value from root to tip. Which could make the v value for example
[image]

[image]

But I cannot find anything for the other coordinate (u). Is there a way to get this information in material nodes?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/293219/165102 ~answer