# Mesh Converted from Hair Particle System Not Following Rigged Object

Tags: rigging, particles, hair, unity

To get hair particles from Blender's particle system to render in unity, they need to be converted to a mesh, which I have done for a cat model I was working on.

After converting though, when I try to join the mesh with the body of the cat, it doesn't work.
I don't know if it has something to do with not being able to join together meshes and rigs but I am really confused and stuck.
It's important for them to be joined, as I need the hair to follow the movement of the cat.

Also, I have asked a similar question and I know that the armature modifier needs to be above the hair particle systems in the modifier hierarchy, and it is, but It is not working as I have converted those modifiers to mesh.

[image: Cat With Hair Mesh not Connected]

/////// EDIT

I have the error no mesh data to join but I cannot figure out why that would be the case

I also added a bevel to all the hair particles under their geometry tab.

Comment: Particles need to be converted to a mesh. But this creates a lot of geometry. This is bad for game engines & a problem for weight painting. For game engines, it's better to use so-called hair cards. That's planes with hair stands and transparency. Here is a random example: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/grizzly-bear-95baabcbc8634f6dace4376767a6024e. the 3D viewer has a model inspector. Switch to Wireframe mode to see the cards. You can use the particle or the new hair curves to lay out the hair cards. Examples: https://youtu.be/oqjKMd9CYI4 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276504/107598

Comment: Have you figured out?