# How to convert UVMap attribute to UV map in blender 3.6

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

UV's generated using Geometry Nodes are stored as attributes, not as UV's, meaning they are not exported and cannot be edited in the UV editor.

In Blender 3.1 there was an [operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.1/bpy.ops.geometry.html?highlight=attribute#bpy.ops.geometry.attribute_convert) to convert attribute UV's into UV maps. See the parameter mode "UV_MAP"

This has since been removed, and I can't currently find a way to convert attribute UV's to UV maps.

Comment: in Blender 3.6, you still can use the UI as in previous versions. It's in the the Data Properties tab > Attributes. There you can use the *Convert Attribute* dropdown menu. Have a look here: [2.2 Create the UV Map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276504/107598)

Comment: Thanks @Blunder, this is indeed a duplicate. And here is a short video showing the steps: https://youtube.com/watch?v=Q8oopkJXE4o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 3.5 there is the possibility in *Geometry Nodes* to save data not only as *Vector* in the geometry, but also as *2D Vector*:

[image]

This also has to do with the fact that since this version UVMaps are treated as attributes, and thus a seamless transfer of the saved values is possible by simply applying the *Geometry Nodes* modifier afterwards, and thus all values that you have saved as *2D Vector* are automatically treated as UVMap:

[image]

Comment: GN's steady progress towards cleanliness :)

Comment: I recently noticed this 2D in choices too, but I didn't think to try if the UV works now. And it was the case for the long time since 3.5! Perhaps we should somehow link to/from this? [How to apply Geometry Nodes with UV maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/228241/60486)