why UVs are empty when exporting alembic?
I have a setup with geonodes, all materials are overlaid via geonodes attributes. When exporting alembic, I can't overlay textures because there is nothing in UVs at all, what do I need to do to convert attributes to real UVs in alembic?
Also, when I switch to Face corner the texture doesn't work correctly





Since you are asking the same question again without sharing more information about your setup (e.g. via https://blend-exchange.com), I can only recommend the answer here again: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299012/. However, since this doesn't really seem to be a solution for you either, the error is probably somewhere in the details of your setup. Therefore again: Further information (blend file) is required.

Also check the export settings again: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export/alembic.html#object-options

i upload project, do you need textures for this?
