# When I convert my Hair system into mesh, It has no tris only curves. How can I turn curves into tris?

Tags: particles, export, bezier-curves, hair, fcurves

I am beginner. And I designed a character in Blender using new Hair system but When I export it as Fbx/Obj, Its hair doesnt show up in unreal or in Mixamo. And I cant see it on 3d viewer apps. I tried and converted into particles and Curves. In Blender It looks like it has thickness but It doesnt have any tris on Blender. How can I turn curves mesh with tris? Or what settings should I use?

[image: Modifiers I used]

[image: The mesh I added hair system]

[image: Particle properties]

[[image: Curves data4]

Comment: First convert curve to mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2917/how-can-curves-be-converted-to-meshes , then quats to tris https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/how-to-make-all-polygons-into-triangles

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Emir When I convert my hair into Mesh it doesnt change curvies into n-gons, They stay the same. So Triangulate/Remesh or soldify modifiers doesnt work.

Comment: If you convert hair particles to mesh you only will get edges and no faces. To give the hair particles some geometry you can use a low-poly object (e.g. a cylinder) for the particle system settings (Render > Render As > Object). Alternatively, a *Particle Instance* modifier on the cylinder will create a similar result. But I wouldn't do this if you want to animate the character because it will create A LOT of geometry. You better use so-called *Hair cards*, that's just planes with hair strand texture on them.

Comment: Most of the Mixamo characters have hair cards. You can download them and have a look. Make sure Alpha Hashed is used in the material settings for the hair. Here is also a video about it, that gives you an overview of how you can use the particle system for the layout of the planes:  [HAIR for AAA GAMES | Blender.Today LIVE](https://www.youtube.com/live/oqjKMd9CYI4?feature=shared) - Related questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276504/107598 -- https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274260/107598 - they use the new Hair Curves (Blender 3) instead of Hair Particles but it works the same